# Is 'OK to board' required on Fly Dubai?

Tags: indian-citizens, albania, flydubai, ecr, ok-to-board

I travel with 3 people, flying to Tirana, Albania from Mumbai.
Right now Albania visa is on arrival for Indian Passport holders till 31 DEC 2022.
I need to check if 'OK to board' is required on Fly Dubai if the passenger passport is ECR (Emigration Check Required).

The airline is not giving any answer so is anybody here able to assist me with this query?

Comment: ECR is for Indian immigration, not the airline. Do you have clearance from immigration office to fly?

Comment: @lambshaanxy does the Indian government require airlines to get an "ok to board" indication before issuing a boarding pass?  Does it take ECR status into account when determining whether to give an "ok to board" indication for an Indian citizen?

Comment: @phoog I'm not really familiar with how the system operates, but last I checked ECR holders need to get a physical Emigration Clearance Certificate for travel to gazetted countries including the UAE.

Comment: Does this help https://www.flydubai.com/en/flying-with-us/passenger-services/ok-to-board/ok-to-board-from-india ?